# what's the meaning of "[ ]" in python references?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using python for a long time. but it was always strange to me why In python references, commands are written like this:
`del var1[,var2[,var3[....,varN]]]]`
I know that if I want to use the above command I should write it in this way:
`del var1, var1`
I can't understand the meaning of `[]` is it related to the lists? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `[,..]` notation usually implies optional arguments

Comment: Note that this is also covered [in the docs themselves](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/introduction.html#notation)

Comment: thank you all. I haven't read its documents before. I just use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just showing that these parameters are optional. This is normal style for references. 
There is nothing to do with this in python. Just a tutorial explanation.

I bealive, this is taken origin from [Usage message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message

Comment: I was interesting the source of this also and I found same article.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: thanks for your attention. I have another question. what is the meaning of dot in this script:  from .averager import averager